# Symfony2 how to configure firewall to handle session for dynamic paths?

Tags: php, symfony, session

I'm interested in the way of configuring symfony2 security firewall to allow users to multiple login for different tenants. Is there any way to set it by the firewall path patter? Or maybe anyone have some ideas how can I solve it?

Let me give you a closer look to the problem i facing:
I have the routs withs look like this: `/{tenant}/.....`

Where `{tenant}` is something common only to group of users.
So i want let users to login in the same time and handle their session for multiple tenants.
If i have 2 users, first is assigned to `tenant1` and second to `tenant2` i want to be able to login (im using `fosuserbundle` and the login path is simply `/login`) on both of them where their paths looks like `/tenant1/ {action}` and `/tenant2/ {action}`. 
How can i do that how can i handle the sessions between different tenants ?

I have all set up (tenants and stuff) just need an idea to handle the sessions.

Comment: will the users always be able to manage the other tenant accounts or do the tenants need to be logged in at the same time and it all depends on the current session?  If each user should have access to several tenants, then maybe you can add a [voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html) to allow access

Comment: one user can access only one tenant, user can not be assigned to both tenants

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature built into symfony that allows users to log in as other users. That might get you what you desire.

However you can only be authenticated as a single user at one time. If you look at the TokenInterface and it's implementation in the security component, you'll notice it only supports a single user at a time.

Comment: i understand that, but you can be logged into 2 different users, using 2 firewalls im not saying i want to allow user to be logged in into 2 user for the same firewall